# matrix addition skipping NaN values

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, nan

I would like to do element wise addition over matrices while skipping *NaN* values. 
MATLAB and Octave have *nansum*, but it does column wise addition within a matrix.

Let:

```
a = NaN * zeros(3)
b = ones(3)
```

I want:

```
c = nan+(a, b)
```

and

```
c = b
```

and:

```
d = nan+(a,a)
```

and

```
d = a
```

Comment: Instead of a = NaN * zeros(3) you can write a = NaN(3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still use nansum, if you catenate your n-d arrays along the n+1st dimension.

For 2D

```
% commands de-nested for readability. You can do this with a single line, of course
tmp = cat(3,a,b);
c = nansum(tmp,3);
```

The general case

```
function out = nansumByElement(A,B)
%NANSUMBYELEMENT performs an element-wise nansum on the n-D arrays A and B
% A and B have to have the same size

% test input
if nargin < 2 || isempty(A) || isempty(B) || ndims(A)~=ndims(B) || ~all(size(A)==size(B))
error('please pass two non-empty arrays of the same size to nansumByElement')
end

% calculate output

nd = ndims(A); % get number of dimensions
% catenate and sum along n+1st dimension
out = nansum(cat(nd+1,A,B),nd+1);
```

Comment: Thanks, that almost does it.  <br>
I still wanted NaN + NaN = NaN and not 0.  <br>
but, even nansum doesn't do that.

Comment: I just added

out(and(isnan(A), isnan(B))) = NaN

and now it works

Answer (score 1):

```
a_fixed = a;
a_fixed(isnan(a)) = 0;
b_fixed = b;
b_fixed(isnan(b)) = 0;
c = a_fixed.+b_fixed;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is how i would have gone about it eventually, but its good to know how to use the cat and nansum method above also.